# Type Casting in Template Functions C++

Tags: c++, templates, types, casting, typeconverter

guys. After lurking on too many threads, not being able to find an answer to the problem I'm having, I've decided to finally post up a question of my own. I'm working on an assignment for school, and for a particular part, it's asking me to write a template function that will take two parameters of different types, then swap the contents of the parameters. Given that it is an assignment for school, I don't expect anyone to just give me the answer. That does kind of defeat the purpose and working through it to learn it, after all. But any hints to get me in the right direction would be much appreciated.

This is basically what I'm working with right now, and I'm pretty much stuck. As far as I can tell, there's no error, as I can build and run it with no problem. I'm just getting wonky values in the output. In the assignment, there was a hint saying to use static_cast, so that's the reason that's in there. I'm not sure if there's a better for way for me to be casting my types when I'm converting, though, or the reason why I'm getting such weird outputs.

```
template<class T1, class T2>
void swap_values(T1& variable1, T2& variable2)
{
    T1 temp;
    cout << "Originals: " << variable1 << " " << variable2 << endl;
    temp = variable1;
    variable1 = static_cast<T1>(variable2);
    variable2 = static_cast<T2>(temp);
    cout << "Results: " << variable1 << " " << variable2 << endl;
}

int main()
{
    char a = '1';
    int b = 1;
    swap_values(a, b);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

For the given variables here, it just reads out "Results: *smiley face* 49" for the second cout line.

Comment: The character `'1'`'s ASCII code is 49.

Comment: Cast both variables to `int` when you print them out.

Comment: T.C. - Ahh, I see. So what's happening is that it's just printing out the ASCII code for the numbers I'm trying to swap.

Comment: Barry - I would, but what I'm supposed to be doing is swapping the parameters, and they aren't always necessarily going to be ints. I just have an int and a char for testing it's functionality right now.